# Arduino enc28j60 tcp stack

Tags: python, tcp, arduino

I want a connection between my arduino and my pc. I've a enc28j60 connected to the arduino. I would like to use tcp packages but I can't find any example code or something. Can someone help me with this? I just want to receive and send tcp packages!

EDIT: ADDING PURPOSE!

I'm designing a rfid system where a rfid cart unlocks a door. You can authorize cards with a web interface and set things like time settings there.

I have made a website with a sql database. I can read this with a simple piece of python. At the other and I have an arduino which can read rfid tags. The problem here is that i want to connect them. Do you have any sugestions!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wire it up correctly, some libraries already exist to make your life easier. Have a look at:

- https://github.com/ntruchsess/arduino_uip
- http://nathanhein.com/2013/02/getting-arduino-online-with-an-enc28j60/
- http://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/connect-an-enc28j60-ethernet-module-to-an-arduino/

Comment: I understand that I have to wire it up correctly and that there are some libery's. The only thing i can't get to work is the tcp stack. How do I send tcp packages from my arduino?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by tcp packages. As I understand you can do tcp or udp. Can you please elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do? Are you trying to make a web server or perform a web request? Have a look at the examples on http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet to see what kinds of things you can do.

Comment: Oke, maby it's better if I explain the whole project.

I'm designing a rfid system where a rfid cart unlocks a door. You can authorize cards with a web interface and set things like time settings there.

I have made a website with a sql database. I can read this with a simple piece of python. At the other and I have an arduino which can read rfid tags. The problem here is that i want to connect them. Do you have any sugestions!

Comment: Http client/server could be easy to implement. Run a web server (sounds like you already have one), and then have the Arduino act as the client and make a request to the webserver asking "can this rfid tag open my door?". Nearly all the code you need is on http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet

Comment: I would also suggest looking at [MySQL Connector/Arduino](http://drcharlesbell.blogspot.com/2013/04/introducing-mysql-connectorarduino_6.html)

Comment: I understand that there is an reference on the arduino site but how do I achieve this with a enc28j60  network chip?